# Jenkins TFS Exception: Why is it happening & how do I fix or workaround?

Tags: jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

I am sometimes getting the following error from TFS plugin in Jenkins:

> FATAL: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

This error is inconsistent and might go away next time I try to run the same job.

- Is there a fix for this issue?
- Is it possible to force a retry on Jenkins TFS?

**Environment**

- Jenkins v2.60.3
- TFS plugin 5.121.0
- Windows 10 64-bit
- Java 1.8

**Console with Stack Traceback From Jenkins**

```
Querying for remote changeset at '$/XXX/YYY' as of 'D0039-09-22T18:26:39Z'...
FATAL: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.SOAPFault: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAP12Service.examineResponseDOMForFault(SOAP12Service.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.examineBodyForFault(SOAPService.java:987)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:665)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequest(SOAPService.java:444)
    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._RepositorySoap12Service.queryHistory(_RepositorySoap12Service.java:1503)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayer.queryHistory(WebServiceLayer.java:1573)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.queryHistory(WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.java:1254)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient.queryHistory(VersionControlClient.java:4264)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.MockableVersionControlClient.queryHistory(MockableVersionControlClient.java:255)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.TECoreExceptionMapper.map(TECoreExceptionMapper.java:92)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.mappers.VersionControlExceptionMapper.map(VersionControlExceptionMapper.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayer.queryHistory(WebServiceLayer.java:1589)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.internal.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.queryHistory(WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.java:1254)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.VersionControlClient.queryHistory(VersionControlClient.java:4264)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.MockableVersionControlClient.queryHistory(MockableVersionControlClient.java:255)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.call(RemoteChangesetVersionCommand.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from JENKINS-NODE/10.0.0.226:13135(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1554)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:281)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:839)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:233)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.execute(Server.java:237)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.extractChangesetNumber(Project.java:280)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:276)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Project.getRemoteChangesetVersion(Project.java:292)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.recordWorkspaceChangesetVersion(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:370)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:319)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
```

Comment: That date it's querying is in the year 39: `'D` `0039` `-09-22T18:26:39Z'...` Any chance you're running tests in a Persian or other calendar notation?

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm not running any tests at this point in the job, I'm just getting source from TFS when this happens.  The date & time on the machine where this is running is correct.  I wonder if there is some inconsistent error in talking to the TFS server and the Jenkins TFS plugin freaks out instead of handling it gracefully sometimes?

Comment: You could try intercepting the traffic using Fiddler to see what is sent over the wire.

Comment: @jessehouwing This seems to happen randomly, so catching it when it happens is difficult.  Is there some way to force a retry on TFS using Jenkins when this or other TFS SCM error happens?

Comment: No clue. I'm from the VSTS/TFS side, so the error makes sense to me. How Jenkins decided to supply this data is beyond me.